# Redo keyboard shortcut for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, ctrl, redo

Does anyone know what the **redo** keyboard shortcut for Eclipse is?

I'm using Linux Mint based on Ubuntu and do all my programming there. I noticed Eclipse supports C, Java, PHP, HTML, Python. I code in all of these languages so I thought it'd be a nice IDE to use, but the redo shortcut is really important to me. I just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> for redo in gedit, but it does not work on Eclipse.

Comment: I actually wanted Ctrl + Y to work *instead of* Ctrl + Shift + Z (which is the default in my version of Eclipse), but this question and answer still answers my question perfectly!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

In Eclipse go to:

```
Window > Preferences > General >  Keys
```

In the keys, scroll down to redo and make it what you want.

Here is [documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_provide_a_keyboard_shortcut_for_my_action%3F).

Here is a screenshot:
[image]